# VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not find a registered machine named 'Windows-PC' while Running from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, virtualbox

Here is the details of my environment.
1. I have two nodes(win7x64 and winserver2008R2) added as slave in Jenkins.
2. I have installed virtualbox to both the system and created virtualbox image with same MachineName, VM Name and Snapshot name.
3. Now I have batch file with following commands:

```
    cd /d "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox"
    VBoxManage snapshot "Windows-PC" restore "CleanPC"
    VBoxManage startvm "Windows-PC"

    VBoxManage --nologo guestcontrol "Windows-PC" execute --image "c:\\IntegrationTestAssemblies\\RunIntegrationTests.bat" --username "user1" --password "pwdddd" --wait-exit --wait-stdout --wait-stderr

    VBoxManage controlvm WindowsPC poweroff
```

*

4. When I run this command manually from host/slaves, it works perfectly. I have checked, vms are registered and *VBoxManage list vms* also returns list of vms.
5. But issue i am facing is, while i am trying to run it through jenkins " using a Multi-configuration project, it fails to launch vm with error

   [exec] C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage.exe snapshot "Windows-PC" restore "CleanPC" 
    [exec] 
    [exec] C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage.exe startvm "Windows-PC" 
    [exec] 
    [exec] 2/25/2015 7:33:18 PM:     error: VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not find a registered machine named 'Windows-PC'
    [exec] VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), component VirtualBox, interface IVirtualBox, callee IUnknown
    [exec] VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "FindMachine(bstrMachine.raw(), ptrMachine.asOutParam())" at line 280 of file VBoxManageSnapshot.cpp
    [exec] VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not find a registered machine named 'Windows-PC'
    [exec] VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), component VirtualBox, interface IVirtualBox, callee IUnknown
    [exec] VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(pszVM).raw(), machine.asOutParam())" at line 575 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
6. Any clue what is wrong with the setup?

Comment: Hello! I have the exact same problem, did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: Solution: Logged in user and Jenkins slave should be running as admin

Answer (score 9):

You can try to first register the virtual machine:

VBoxManage registervm your_virtual_machine.vbox